# I was offline on whatsapp for one month, when I connected my WhatsApp to Internet, I didn't get all messages

Tags: whatsapp

What is happening? What should I do now?

Comment: How do you know whether anyone had sent you any messages during that time?

Answer (score 2):

From WhatsApp FAQ - [Data Retention and Availability](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/26000050/?category=5245250):

> ... undelivered messages are deleted from our servers after 30 days.

So, this might be a reason for why you didn't got all your messages.

About what should you do now - you don't have much to do - the messages are probably gone. Your best shot is asking the ones who sent you messages to re-send them.

Besides that, from my experience - after not connecting to WhatsApp for relatively long time, the chances increase that the messages order won't be reliable/consistent with the order they were sent.